# How to change the layout of Chrome's top bar (tabs and address)?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Is it possible to modify the topbar (tabs and address) of the browser Chrome?

I'd like to have it look like Firefox Version 3. Is that possible?

So far, I've only found out, that I can apply themes, but they only change the colour of the topbar, not the design.

Comment: Ah, here we have it ... a browser that has nearly no visible UI and people even want to customize that tiny bit. Interesting though, that some people seem to look at the browser's window frame more often than at the site content ;-)

Comment: Too tiny for my opinion. That's why I asked for the possibility of customization

Comment: There is no reason of changing it. Why waste space for title bar like firefox?

Answer (score 2):

> How to change the layout of Chrome's top bar (tabs and address)?
>
> Did Google announce anything like they are planning on doing so?

Quite the opposite; the devs have repeatedly indicated that they have no intention of letting users alter the physical dimensions of the browser chrome (ie, themes *only* change colors and textures), by always closing such [requests](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) and flagging them as **Won’t Fix**.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. At the moment you can't change the layout of the chrome of chrome .. :)

Comment: Did Google announce anything like they are planning on doing so? Chrome is so great, except for the UI :-|

Comment: i really doubt it.